# Are there default directories which are searched for programs in Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, path

In Windows 10 and cmd, when running a program, is it searched in some directory not in `Path` by default? After I installed a program into its default dir under `C:\Program Files`, the program name isn't found in cmd by default.

In Ubuntu, we can put an executable under `/usr/bin`, which is searched by default, though I am  not sure if it is included in `PATH` by default.

Thanks.

Comment: "the program name isn't found in cmd by default." - So add the path to the executable to path variable.

Answer (score 1):

`C:\Program Files\` is not in the the default path for Windows, nor would it search subdirectories if it was.  You will have to manually [add the path](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/how-can-i-add-new-folder-my-system-path) to the executable's folder to the path variable in Windows.